# Today minus 30 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run an query/create filter, within a program, every day WHERE last_paid is TODAY - 30 and TODAY = `convert(varchar,getdate(),101)`. The biggest issue seems to be the inflexiblity of the program to have today be anything other than `convert(varchar,getdate(),101)`.

Comment: `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);` tell to program to save dates in appropriate `Date` or `DateTime` format.

Comment: Out of curiousity, which DBMS are you using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.)?

Comment: Why are you converting `GETDATE()`? TODAY should be stored as a DATE. What do you mean inflexibility of the program?! Are you referring to your program or are you referring to you DBMS? If you are you may want to look into `DATEADD` before making such statements.

Comment: This is hosted CRM, that uses SQL loosely as their database. When creating a filter where the date is to be exactly equal to today, I get the convert(varchar,getdate(),101). It seems the dates are not stored as 'DATES'.

Comment: SQL is a language not a database.

Comment: @ChrisForrence syntax appears to be SQL Server.

Comment: What do you mean by, "it seems the dates are not stored as dates"?  What did you look at to make this inference?

Answer (score 4):

This is going to be a short answer because this is an incredibly easy problem. You want to use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) your syntax should be something like `TODAY = convert(varchar,DATEADD(DAY,-30,getdate()),101)`

**UPDATE:** I still think you need to address the issue you have of TODAY beings stored as some sort of string. If this were a `DATE` datatype you wouldn't have to deal with this convert nonsense.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! Many 'solutions' out there but none with the varchar thrown in to the mix.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here?

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME

SELECT @Today = GETDATE() - 30

SELECT @Today AS [Today - 30]
```

If you don't want the time, don't make it a DateTime data type, instead use DATE:

```
DECLARE @Today DATE

SELECT @Today = GETDATE() - 30

SELECT @Today AS [Today - 30]
```

Comment: There is not access to the actual SQL to look (or edit).

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle try:

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '30' days
```